# Not able to change the global value of the given class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to change the value of **idCity** of the given class in kotlin

```
class City_Id(private var cityName: String) {


    var idCity : String? = null

    val url = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query="


    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "$url$cityName", null,
            { response ->
                    val cityInfo : JSONObject = response.getJSONObject(0)
                    var cityID : String = cityInfo.getString("woeid")
                    
                    idCity = cityID
                    makeLog(cityID)
                   

                makeLog("from json $idCity")
            },
            { error ->
                    makeLog("$error")

            }

    )

    fun jsonReturn(): JsonArrayRequest {
        return this.jsonObjectRequest
    }


    private fun makeLog(s: String) {
        Log.d("City_Id Activity" , s)

    }

}
```

The variable "idCity" that I changed locally in "jsonObjectRequest" want to change it globally in class "City_Id". When calling "idCity" from different class
it still returning null after changing its value.
Thank you in advance

Comment: check if the cityID is not null while setting it

Comment: I tried putting some value instead of null but still not working

Comment: You'll have to show what you're actually trying, what you expect, and what you get. The code above doesn't tell us anything about what you're trying and what's going wrong.

Comment: why dont you use livedata. try to use that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `JsonArrayRequest` is asynchronous and it won't set the global `idCity` variable as soon as `City_id` class `instance` is created. So if you access the `idCity` property from else where, you will get `null` till the `request` is complete. The better way to handle this is to pass an `function`  as parameter to `City_id` class and then on response pass invoke the function with value.

Something of below sorts

```
class City_Id(private var cityName: String, block:(idCity: String) -> Unit) {
    val url = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query="
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "$url$cityName", null,
            { response ->
                    val cityInfo : JSONObject = response.getJSONObject(0)
                    var cityID : String = cityInfo.getString("woeid")
                    makeLog(cityID)
                    block.invoke(cityId)//pass to caller
            },
            { error ->
                    makeLog("$error")

            })

    fun jsonReturn(): JsonArrayRequest {
        return this.jsonObjectRequest
    }
 
    private fun makeLog(s: String) {
        Log.d("City_Id Activity" , s)

    }
}
```

And at caller side

```
City_id("name"){idCity ->
    //here you will definitely get the city Id
}
```

Comment: There is still problem while accessing idCity in "makeLog("from json $idCity")"

Comment: Just remove that line, there is no need for idCity